# Как убрать переход на новую строку после вывода масива циклом

Tags: c

Я пишу на С, и столкнулся с проблемой связаной с переходом на новую строку после цикла. Меня интереснует как убрать этот переход, что бы данные были в одну строку.[image: Код]
[image: Вывод]

```
printf("\nYour database of workers: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("#%d ", i);
        for(int j = 0; j < nameLen[i]; j++) printf("%c", lastName[i][j]);
        printf(" ");
        for(int j = 0; j < departmentLen[i]; j++) printf("%c", departmentName[i][j]);
        printf(" ");
        for(int j = 0; j < positionLen[i]; j++) printf("%c", position[i][j]);
        printf(" %d %d %d\n", birtday[i], workExp[i], salary[i]);
    }



void input_lastName(char **lastName, int *nameLen, int i)
{
    char *buffer; //Ввод текстовых данных
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100 + 1);
    printf("Print the lastName of worker#%d:", i);
    fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
    nameLen[i] = strlen(buffer);
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(buffer); j++) 
    lastName[i][j] = buffer[j];
    free(buffer); 
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Похоже, у вас символ `\n` находится в самих данных. Или изначально не пишите его в данные (здесь вы не показали, как вы это делаете), или, если уж вы так хитро выводите - посимвольно - то проверяйте, не равен ли выводимый символ `\n`...

Comment: Ввожу данные для текстовых переменных довольно глупо, но это единственное что я придумал кроме того, что бы вводить посимвольно :)
http://joxi.ru/gmvED9vSq6BbWr

Comment: скорее всего последний символ при вводе это и есть `\n`, попробуйте выводить информацию до `nameLen[i]-1`

Comment: @Komdosh Спасибо огромное, я попался на элементарном... 
Не знаю как тегнуть всех кто откликнулись, но вам тоже спасибо :))